# Deny a user access to a group-owned folder without removing him from group?

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, directory

I have a group-owned folder in Ubuntu.
Let's name it Finance.
There are 3 users in that group, Fin1, Fin2, FinX.
These users are the only ones who have access to this folder.
How can we deny FinX his access to the folder without removing him from the group?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a different group, make it a supplementary group for `Fin1` and `Fin2`, but not `FinX`, and assign that as the group for the folder in question and all its contents.

Or if that's too much like removing `FinX` from the group then the main alternatives I see are ACLs and SELinux.  Either one of these would be moving onto rather less trodden ground.  Both rely on the directory residing on a file system that supports extended file attributes, which it probably does if it supports standard file permission bits, as you imply it does.

The ACL approach might be implemented via a command similar to this:

```
setfacl --recursive -m d:u:FinX:0 -m u:FinX:0 /path/to/directory
```

I rarely work with ACLs, so that may be a bit off.  Once it's done, though, new files and subdirectories should inherit the same restriction, because the command sets it in both the access ACL and the default ACL.